# Export a query with parameters as a .csv

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to export a query as a .csv but the query has parameters. I can get the query to run but when I try to export it I get the error:

"Runtime Error 3828

Cannot reference a table with a multi valued field using an IN clause that refers to another database"

```
 Private Sub EthosRpt_Click()

 DoCmd.OpenQuery "EthosSessions"

 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "EthosSessions", "C:\[file path]\test.csv"

 End Sub
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any help?

Comment: Found the following link with a quick search on "Runtime Error 3828": https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c08e2e1-42c2-4f7f-9eb4-32e2b71e5b6c/runtime-error-3828-for-docmdtransferspreadsheet-access-2010?forum=accessdev  -- are you using a linked table? You might want to try converting the query to a Make Table query, dump the data into a temp table, then export the temp table.

Comment: That looks like it's going to work. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have a new question. How can I specify the path of the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLibby was right. 
Make Table query fixed the whole issue.